# ROS Answers SE migration: libuvc kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, usb-cam, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried to install libuvc or libuvc_ros for kinetic distribution? I have no idea how it should be done.

> Maybe using  https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239728/libuvc-kinetic/) by [glagla](https://answers.ros.org/users/27526/glagla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As by today it is not possible to install `libuvc_ros` via apt-get.
Here are the steps to install `libuvc_ros` manually under ROS kinetic:

```
# Install dependencies, as I wasn't able to install them via rosdep
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0 libusb-1.0-0-dev

# Clone libuvc_ros and libuvc to your workspace
cd /path/to/your/workspace/src
git clone https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros.git
git clone https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc.git

# The following instructions come from the libuvc's Readme file
mkdir libuvc/build
cd libuvc/build
cmake ..
make && sudo make install

# Run catkin
cd /path/to/your/workspace
catkin_make
```

---

Originally posted by [Andre Volk](https://answers.ros.org/users/29707/andre-volk/) with karma: 775 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0